# What is the wrong & how to compute the following program

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, if-statement

The following is a dataframe:

```
  GENDER PROMOTE
  M      1
  M      0
  M      2
  F      1
  M      0
  F      2
  F      1
  F      1
  M      2
  F      0
  F      2
  F      1
```

M=Male; F=Female

Now i have to find out the number of female who are

(a) PROMOTE==0 ; (b) PROMOTE==1 ; (c) PROMOTE==2

#### My attempt:

```
data <- read.table("sum.txt",header=TRUE)
data

 s1=0;s2=0;s3=0

 for(i in 1:12){
   if(data$GENDER[i]==F & data$PROMOTE[i]==0){
     s1=s1+1
   } else if (data$GENDER[i]==F & data$PROMOTE[i]==1){
       s2=s2+1
    } else if (data$GENDER[i]==F & data$PROMOTE[i]==2){
        s3=s3+1
      }}
```

But s1,s2,s3 have not been modified. Those have their initial values. Also no error has been occurred.

What is/are the problem(s) here? And the alternative way to compute the task.

Comment: `F` is different from `"F"`, also you want `&&` not `&`. But there are much better tools to solve the problem in R. Please make your example reproducible by providing `dput(data)`

Comment: as baptiste mentioned, take a look at `?table`:  `table(data$GENDER, data$PROMOTE)`. I'd also recommend taking a few minutes and reading some of the intro to R guides on the web, they will be quite informative!

Comment: Or simply `table(data)`.

Comment: more specifically `with(subset(data,GENDER=="F"),table(PROMOTE))`

Comment: you can find the basic functions for data management in R [here](http://www.statmethods.net/management/index.html)

Comment: Thank you, all. for the nice solution and reference.

Answer (score 0):

using `plyr`:

```
ddply(data[data$GENDER=='F',], .(GENDER),count)
```

get:

```
  GENDER PROMOTE freq
1      F       0    1
2      F       1    4
3      F       2    2
```

Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: splitting a dataset by GENDER when you've already selected one subset seems quite odd.

Comment: Agree. If not for the original request, I would drop this condition or do `aaa<-ddply(data, .(GENDER), count)
; aaa[aaa$GENDER=='F',]
`